# pre-commit/hook: No such file or directory

Tags: git, pre-commit-hook, pre-commit

I get this error when I try to commit.

OS - Latest OSX

Git version - git version 2.11.0 (Apple Git-81)

```
.git/hooks/pre-commit: line 2: ./node_modules/pre-commit/hook: No such file or directory
```

Comment: You have a pre-commit hook defined (in `.git/hooks/pre-commit`) and it is trying to reference `./node_modules/pre-commit/hook` which doesn't exist. If the hook is no longer needed you can just delete it.

Answer (score 129):

pre-commit hook runs first when you try to commit changes, it can be used to do certain checks, tests, conditions. In this case, clearly, you don't have it, that's why it's complaining.

Go to `.git/hooks` directory and remove `pre-commit` file, as its trying to reference to `node_modules/pre-commit/hook`. It should resolve it.

Other option is append your commit with option: `--no-verify`, it will make the commit without checking.

Comment: I got exactly the same error which means suggests something is wrong with the `gem webpacker` and webpack installation process; because that's what I just had done. But odd that the `pre-commit` file was last modified six months ago. But the removal of the `pre-commit` file fixed my problem.

Comment: I got same issue but it is not solved by removing `pre-commit` file. Than i tried to commit by command in terminal and add `--no-verify` command at last so my command is `git commit -m "message" --no-verify`. It is working for me.

Comment: This can happen if Lint is setup to enforce formatting rules. As @Mutant and  @KomalGoyani mentioned, you can bypass the Lint check using `git commit -n (or --no-verify)`

Answer (score 18):

You should delete `node_modules` folder and install again running `npm install` or `yarn install`. After it, you probably solve the problem.

Answer (score 10):

If the script files are actually present, then the cause may be that the first line of the script should be something like:

`#!/bin/sh`

Otherwise you get the same error.

Any file will work -- e.g., `/bin/bash`, `/usr/local/bin/python3` -- as long as it exists and is executable.

Answer (score 10):

Following @Mutant tip, the simple answer for me was:

```
rm .git/hooks/pre-commit
```

Answer (score 5):

Working from macOS, my issue was that Python3 was originally installed via Homebrew, and after I upgraded Python3 via `brew update && brew upgrade`, I got the same error.

To fix this, I needed to update the symbolic links in the directory that the shebang (`#!`) line in the `.git/hooks/pre-commit` file points to.

Here's how I fixed this in my environment:

1. Look at the contents of the `.git/hooks/pre-commit`:

   ```sh
   cat .git/hooks/pre-commit
   ```

   The first few lines should look something like:

   ```
   #!/usr/local/opt/pre-commit/libexec/bin/python3
   # File generated by pre-commit: https://pre-commit.com
   # ID: 0123456789abcdef0123456789abcdef
   import os
   import sys
   ```

   Take note of the path to the `python3` executable in the shebang line:

   ```
   /usr/local/opt/pre-commit/libexec/bin/
   ```
2. `cd` into that directory.

   ```sh
   cd /usr/local/opt/pre-commit/libexec/bin/
   ```
3. Take at look at the Python symlinks:

   ```sh
   ls -l | grep python
   ```

   You'll see some symlinks that are probably broken:

   ```
   lrwxr-xr-x  1 user  group    91 Apr  5 13:33 python -> /usr/local/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.2_4/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/bin/python3.9
   lrwxr-xr-x  1 user  group    91 Apr  5 13:33 python3.9 -> /usr/local/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.2_4/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/bin/python3.9
   lrwxr-xr-x  1 user  group    91 Apr  5 13:33 python3 -> /usr/local/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.2_4/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/bin/python3.9
   ```

   Quick note: In case something goes wrong or my answer isn't the solution, you might want to back up these symlinks first by running:

   ```sh
   mv python python.bak
   ```

   ```sh
   mv python3.9 python3.9.bak
   ```

   ```sh
   mv python3 python3.bak
   ```
4. Update the symbolic links using `ln -s [PATH] [LINK]`, where `[PATH]` is the location of the Homebrew-updated Python3 executable and `[LINK]` is `python`, `python3.9`, and `python3`:

   ```sh
   ln -s /usr/local/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.4/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/bin/python3.9 python
   ```

   ```sh
   ln -s /usr/local/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.4/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/bin/python3.9 python3.9
   ```

   ```sh
   ln -s /usr/local/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.4/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/bin/python3.9 python3
   ```
5. When you've done that, list your Python symlinks again.

   ```sh
   ls -l | grep python
   ```

   You should see the updated symlinks, and `git commit` should now work.

   ```
   lrwxr-xr-x  1 user  group    89 Apr  6 13:58 python -> /usr/local/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.4/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/bin/python3.9
   lrwxr-xr-x  1 user  group    89 Apr  6 13:58 python3 -> /usr/local/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.4/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/bin/python3.9
   lrwxr-xr-x  1 user  group    89 Apr  6 13:58 python3.9 -> /usr/local/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.4/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/bin/python3.9
   ```

Answer (score 1):

I got that error after I was played with brew to make yarn work in Webstorm.

The fix is just re-install pre-commit again.

`brew install pre-commit`

https://pre-commit.com/

Answer (score 0):

```sh
INGW64 ~/code/ingestor-gdelt (test-build)
$ git commit -m "your comment"
```

.git/hooks/pre-commit: line 9: py: command not found

.git/hooks/pre-commit: line 10: py: command not found

```sh
git commit --no-verify -m "your comment"
```

This command resolved my issue !!

Comment: it solves the problem temporarily, but it also skips your pre-commit  task and doesn't really resolve the issue. Its just a workaround to bypass the error.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who is having this problem with husky, for me what solved it is running:

`husky install`

(which I forgot to run) The docs talk about it under `usage`, aka `npm run prepare` for one time after you set up husky. [usage](https://www.npmjs.com/package/husky#usage)

Answer (score 0):

Nothing helps me but remove local repo and clone it again. This kinda error appears when I accidentically tried commit and push changes to master..

Answer (score 0):

If you look at your package.json you will get a better idea about the problem.
**Husky** is npm dependency so basically you got the error because for some reason it's not available.
So, option one run

```
npm i
```

Or if you already did that

```
rm -rf node_modules
npm i
```

Answer (score 0):

I had installed pre-commit using homebrew, and installed the pre-commit-vscode extension and got this error.

What solved this was to also run `pre-commit install` from the root of the git repo.

Answer (score 0):

In my case in Mac OS, upgrading `python3` via brew somehow messed up `python3` location whereas the `shebang` in `pre-commit` was was still pointing to the old `python3` location. So finding new `python3` location via `which python3` and updating same in `pre-commit` and other scripts under `.githooks` folder did fixed the issue.

Answer (score -3):

Deleting `pre-commit` from hooks inside `.git` worked for me

Answer (score -3):

just make sure you have hooks folder inside of .git . if not make one.