# How do I solve the following git error: No such file or directory

Tags: reactjs, git, pre-commit-hook, pre-commit

I have done some updates to my React project and when I try to commit I get the following:

```sh
> git -c diff.mnemonicprefix=false -c core.quotepath=false
> --no-optional-locks commit -q -F C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Temp\e3x0kha2.snk
> .git/hooks/pre-commit: line 2: ./node_modules/pre-commit/hook: No such
> file or directory
```

How do I solve this?

Comment: Does [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43933490/2873538) help?

Comment: Have you tied deleting your node_modules and installing them ?